# Is there a specific name for a function that takes its output as input and does that parameter have a name?

Tags: function, recursion, parameters

I work with a BASIC programming language and have found it useful to write functions that rely on their output as a parameter. Such as

```
    inOut = someFunction(inOut)
```

I'd like to call this a recursive function. but it doesn't seem right because it is not calling itself. Can someone tell me what the name of this type of function is and if the parameter/return has a special name? 
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

This is an ordinary function as any other. The thing you show is called reassingment. You can rename `inOut` on the left with `newinOut` and it will not change anything... there is absolutely nothing special about the function, it's a naming pattern, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

In many languages (including VB, but not  sure about classic BASIC) there's something called *passing parameter by reference*. It's not exactly what you posted, but rather simple

```
someFunction(inOut)
```

parameter is passed into the function, changed there and the change persists outside the function